# Open all PDF or docx link as iframe

Tags: plugins, pdf

I have posts in my WordPress as a link for pdf like this:-

```
To show Doc place click here :-
http://domain.com/2012-04/item-1335086631.pdf
```

I need to convert this link to embed to show file in my site.

for all document file (PDF , Doc ...)

How can do that.

Comment: Please don't abandon your question. This question has been answered, yet you did not leave any feedback of any sort. No one, not even the user answering knows whether or not your issue is solved or not. Please see [help] and read the sections why voting is important and what you should do if someone answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [vanilla-pdf-embed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/vanilla-pdf-embed/).

If the PDF is in your Wordpress media library, it will be embedded with the default settings in all the posts where it is written. If isn't in the media library then use the [pdf]...[/pdf] shorttag:

```
[pdf]http://domain.com/2012-04/item-1335086631.pdf[/pdf]
```